# Check if minimum K moves are required for a TSP in 2D Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

**Short Explanation:**
Given to us a `2D grid` , integer `K >= 0` and a starting point `x, y` in  a grid. We are asked to check if a path length of `K` or `greater` exists such that we **start and end at the starting point**. 
The grid contains either `'.'` or `'*'`. We can't visit cells having `'*'`. Also, We must visit each `'.'` cell at-most once. Possible moves are `UP` , `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`

**Problem Link:** 
 
[ALCATRAZ3](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ALCATRAZ3/)

**My Approach:**

We start from the starting point and do all "possible" moves i.e `UP` , `DOWN`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`. For each possible move, we transit from state `s_i` to state `s_j` and we decrement the count of `K`, while marking `s_i` as visited. If we arrive in the starting point again with `K <= 0`, then the answer is `"YES"` else we backtrack to previous state and do the next possible move. 
To optimize it, I used a variable to see if we have already found a route that satisfies the constraints or not. If the variable is set we just return and don't explore to new states from the current state.

I took care of some following corner cases:-

- If `K > N * M` , ans should be `NO`
- If starting point is `'*'`, ans should be `NO`
- If `K = 0` and starting point is `'.'` ans should be `YES`

I'm getting a **Wrong Answer** with this approach. 
Please note that this is an exponential solution to the problem but it is sufficient to solve this particular problem. You can find my code 
  [here](http://ideone.com/JrYEP5).

 
Thanks.

Comment: You didn't ask a question - do you want us to help fix your approach (if possible) or provide an approach that works? If you want us to help you figure out what's wrong with your approach, you need to find and post an example for which it fails yourself, and post the code in the question itself instead of just linking to it.

Comment: @Dukeling: I really don't know where my code fails. I have tried almost 50-60 self generated test-cases but it gives the expected answer. I'd be glad if you could find any corner test-case or suggest me a completely different approach. Thanks :)

Comment: And you're sure it's actually wrong answer, and not time limit exceeded?

Comment: Yeah, I got a wrong answer in the test-case 4. :/ I think I saw in the comments that the exponential time solution passes. The test cases may be weak.